# css3 пропорции отображения

Tags: css, разметка

Почти сделал сайт (http://comp-serv.by). На мониторах с пропорцией 4:3, а так же на мобильных устройствах он отображается более-менее нормально. Но "засада" для широкоформатных мониторов. Хотелось бы стартовый слайд несколько ужать по высоте. А для этого мне как-то нужно в `media-запросах` CSS обнаружить "сей факт".

**Собственно вопрос**

Как определить что текущая видимая область отображения шире чем 4:3?

В медиа-запросах есть параметры, производные от "aspect ratio", что можно с ними сделать по моему вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

> Как определить что текущая видимая область отображения шире чем 4:3?

Широкоэкранный дисплей с соотношением сторон 16:9 может быть помечен как (aspect-ratio: 16/9)

Comment: Увы, меня не интересуют параметры устройства - нужны параметры текущей отображаемой области. И да ... параметры устройства проверяются по device-aspect-ratio.